# Is there a difference between a "key" and "key=" URL query string?

Tags: javascript, url, firefox, query-string

For example, when we parse this query string:

```
foo&bar=&baz=123
```

Firefox’s implementation of the standard `URLSearchParams` type ([spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlsearchparams)) assigns an empty string value to both `foo` and `bar`:

[image]

Does this mean that `foo` and `foo=` are effectively the same inside a query string? Or is it a bug in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the specification in the link that you post...

> For each byte sequence bytes in sequences, run these substeps:
>
> 1. If bytes is the empty byte sequence, run these substeps for the next byte sequence.
> 2. If bytes contains a `=`, then let name be the bytes from the start of bytes up to but excluding its first `=`, and let value be the bytes, if any, after the first `=` up to the end of bytes. If `=` is the first byte, then name will be the empty byte sequence. If it is the last, then value will be the empty byte sequence.
> 3. Otherwise, let name have the value of bytes and let value be the empty byte sequence

so... key and key= are the same... this is not a bug.